# Nearest elements in mltidimensional lattice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a numpy array akin to this one

```
  [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

and I'd like to select a + sign around a specific element to do some computations on. So if, for example, i select array[1,2], I want to return a list with 3 ones and 1 zero. If I select array[0,3], I want to return 2 ones and 1 zero.

I've run in to this problem before and aside from hardcoding something crazy, I figured I'd ask if there was a ready made function that has this functionality.

In clearer language, if I select element array[x1, x2, x3, ..., xn] I'm looking for a function that takes the input [x1, x2, ..., xn] and outputs all direct neighbours.

Answer (score 1):

Modify this to get rid of conditions where the slices run off the array edge:

```
import numpy as np
def get_neighbors(array, indices, delta):
     slices = [slice(idx - delta, idx + delta + 1) for idx in indices]
     return array[slices]

test_arr = np.array(range(100)).reshape((10, 10))
neighbors = get_neighbors(test_arr, [3, 5], 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

couldn't resist rolling my early tries 'for' loops into a single nested list comprehension

```
def ner(a, idx):
    sh = a.shape    
    return [a[ni]
            for ni in [tuple(idx[0:k] + [idx[k] + i] + idx[k+1:])
                       for k in range(len(idx))
                        for i in [1, -1]
                         if 0 <= idx[k] + i < sh[k]]]

import numpy as np

a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

a
Out[72]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

ner(a, [1,1])
Out[73]: [7, 1, 5, 3]

ner(a, [0, 1])
Out[74]: [4, 2, 0]

ner(a, [0, 0])
Out[75]: [3, 1]

b = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)

b
Out[77]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])

ner(b, [2, 2, 2])
Out[78]: [17, 23, 25]

ner(b, [1, 1, 1])
Out[79]: [22, 4, 16, 10, 14, 12]
```